# remapping volume up to power button on nexus 5

Tags: root-access, nexus-5, buttons, power-on, xposed-framework

my power button is half broken. I have rooted my phone and installed xposed framework and xposed additions. I have successfully remapped my volume-up so that when the phone is on I can switch it off or unlock it with volume-up. But I don't manage to switch on my phone. Can anyone point out the correct configuration of xposed that allows this? or suggest an alternative route?